# "The getter 'x' was called on null" for accelerometer data

Tags: flutter, dart, null, accelerometer, getter

I am calling the X, Y, Z data in numerical format from the accelerometer. I am able to call this data without issue after the app is launched. On app launch I get the following error:

```
The getter 'toStringAsFixed' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toStringAsFixed
```

`x1.toStringAsFixed` is called in a TableRow-child-Text field. Because flutter/dart is asynchronous I am sure this error is called because the app tries to display the accelerometer data before it is avalible.

I am unsure of how to delay calling the Text field until data has been populated. I have tried using `if == null` statements etc, but none of my attempts has fixed this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added `if (y1.toStringAsFixed == null)` for each of the 3 axis in an attempt to fix the null error. I tweaked this code to be `if (y1 == null)` for each axis and now the error has been fixed.

I see that by calling null on the `toStringAsFixed` that it is still trying to pull data to check if that data is null, not checking to see if what it will pull is null.